# phonegap update file from external server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

hi
i have a fully working phonegap application with a number of files (both .csv and .jpg) that i would like to check for updates on a web server (say example.com/app) when certain pages are loaded. if there are new files i would like to overwrite the files on the phone app with these updated files

for example:
when you click to:

page2.html, check for updates on 2.csv and 2.jpg

Thanks in advice

Tim

Comment: Still trying to find the right tool for the job, i have found: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/FileDownLoadApp and am trying to see if this will work for me

Comment: Hi!! Have you found any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into client side HTML5 storage.

I'm using the HTML5 sqllite database to store json objects relating to each page within my app. I then have a master configuration file which is in essence a sitemap with each app page, and a timestamp, when I check against the webserver configuration file copy I run a comparison to see if any files are out of date/even new and if so download and store within the client database.

Also take a look at

https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

Hope this helps

regards
Andrew

Comment: Unfortunately i have more than 10MB of data, so the database is out im afraid.

Comment: i have rearranged my data so i now only have 4MB downloadable and lawnchair is working great thankyou!

Comment: How did you use lawnchair to update those files?  It seems like it's a datastore, but how do you use it to replace your resources?

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML page, the same originator rule will restrict you from reading the files in javascript.
I guess you have to create a method in the phonegap wrapper which will check for the files. This method can be called from within javascript.

Comment: Yes, i was wondering about the javascript method that would be used to check for and download the new files